# Impelement promise in JS

Tags: node.js, express

I have a function located in /models/profile.js:

```
module.exports = {
    getDataProfil : function(id_user){
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id_user = ?", [id_user], function(err, rows, fields){
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log(rows[0]);

        });
    }
}
```

I want to call the getDataProfile inside /controllers/profile.js

```
module.exports.profil_get = function(req, res, next) {
    profile_model.getDataProfil(req.user.id_user).then();


}
```

I want to implement promise there, since I need to render the page. How to do it? Thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this, You can also use `q` module too.

```
module.exports = {
  getDataProfil: function(id_user) {
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id_user = ?", [id_user], function(err, rows, fields) {
      if (err) return ['err', err];
      return [null, rows[0]];
    });
  }
}
```

And `profil_get` will be:

```
module.exports.profil_get = function(req, res, next) {
  profile_model.getDataProfil(req.user.id_user)
    .then(function(res) {
      console.log(res);
    });
}
```

Check if `res[0]` is `null` for success or is a string for rejection.

Another implementation is

```
module.exports = {
  getDataProfil: function(id_user) {
    var dfd = q.defer();
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id_user = ?", [id_user], function(err, rows, fields) {
      if (err) { dfd.reject(err); }
      else { dfd.resolve(rows[0]); }
    });
  }
  return dfd.promise;
}
```

And `profil_get`:

```
module.exports.profil_get = function(req, res, next) {
  profile_model.getDataProfil(req.user.id_user)
    .then(function(res) {
      console.log(res);
    })
    .catch(function(err){
       console.log(err);
     });
}
```

Comment: "Check if res[0] is null for success or is a string for rejection". What do it mean?

Comment: In `profil_get` you have `res` that is an array. We create this array in `getDataProfil` with this logic: **1-**if an error occurred, put 'err' as first item and the second one is error message. **2-**if there is no error, put `null` as first item in array and the result as second one. You must check this array in `profil_get` function and create true conditions.

Comment: thankyou so much bro. I use q package. It works well. GBU :)

Comment: Ok. Oh one more question. How if i want to do query chains with promise? Assume if i want to update password, i need to query to db first then update the db.

Comment: There are 2 different things you must know: first, your queries are parallel, you must use `q.all`. read about that. second, you have nested queries like this example you said. you put promise inside another and when all tasks done, you call `dfd.resolve` where you want. Look https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RyNgvG?editors=1010  @hfbachri_

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170307/discussion-between-hfbachri-and-saeed-ataee).

Answer (score 1):

Using native promises:

```
module.exports = {
  getDataProfile : function ( id_user ) {
    return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
      connection.query( 'SELECT * FROM user WHERE id_user = ?', [ id_user ], function ( err, rows, fields ) {
        if ( err ) {
          return reject( err );
        }
        return resolve( rows[ 0 ] );
      } );
    } );
  }
};
```

You can then call your promise and handle response/error cases. Ideally, you would respond to a client instead of using `console.log/error`:

```
module.exports.profile_get = function(req, res, next) {
  profile_model.getDataProfile(req.user.id_user).then( response => {
    console.log( response );
  }).catch( err => {
    console.error( err );
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use native Promise constructor:

```
module.exports = {
    getDataProfil : function(id_user) {
      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id_user = ?", [id_user], function (err, rows, fields) {
            if (err) return reject(err);
            return resolve(rows[0]);
        });
      })
    }
}
```